# Ant sql task - print executed query and result with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ant

I'm trying to print executed query and also result of the query on PostgreSQL.  I have simple ant sql task, using standard postgresql JDBC driver.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <project name="Ant SQL task" default="sql">

   <target name="sql">
      <echo>Ant SQL task</echo>
      <sql
    driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://hostname:port/database"
    userid="user"
    password="password"
    src="script.sql"
    print="yes"
    >

    </sql>
   </target>    
</project>
```

The script.sql containts just

```
select 1 as test;
```

I'm getting this output:

```
info:
      [sql] Executing resource: script.sql
      [sql] test
      [sql] 1
      [sql]
      [sql] 0 rows affected
      [sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
```

I would like to print the select query in the output like this:

```
info:
      [sql] Executing resource: script.sql
      [sql] select 1 as test;
      [sql] test
      [sql] 1
      [sql]
      [sql] 0 rows affected
      [sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
```

Is there a way to include the select query in the output?

Answer (score 0):

1.)  Set [loglevel](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html#connection-parameters) to DEBUG (2) for the jdbc.  Except now you don't have too little info in your log file, but too much.

2.) Append your queries a little:

```
SELECT 1 as foo, (SELECT query FROM pg_stat_activity);
 foo |                         query                          
-----+--------------------------------------------------------
   1 | SELECT 1 as foo, (SELECT query FROM pg_stat_activity);
(1 row)
```

Note that this will give you *all* running queries, not just the current one. You can narrow it down by one of the many columns in `pg_stat_activity`, but that's probably unnecessary unless this is a busy system.   Set `ApplicationName` in your connection parameters if you decide to do that.

3.) Add lines to `script.sql` that manually repeat the next query:

```
SELECT 'SELECT 1;';
SELECT 1;
SELECT 'SELECT 2;';
SELECT 2;
```

4.) Ditch the ant sql module and use [exec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) to run `psql -e -f script.sql` instead:

```
SELECT 1;
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

You can omit the row count with `-P footer=OFF`.